# cv::SVD::compute - U matrix is not orthogonal

Tags: opencv

matrix U from opencv::SVD::compute is not orthogonal

```
float dataH[3][3] = {{ 25079040., -2.22029547e+005, -8.73665188e+005 }, 
                     { 2811925.,  -2441455.,        -68310968. },
                     { 0.,        0.,               0. }};
cv::Mat H( 3, 3, CV_32F, dataH );

cv::Mat S, U, Vt;
cv::SVD::compute(H, S, U, Vt, cv::SVD::FULL_UV);
std::cout << "U" << std::endl << U << std::endl << std::endl;

cv::Mat Ut;
cv::transpose( U, Ut );
std::cout << "U * Ut" << std::endl << U * Ut << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
U
[-0.032228146, -0.99948055, 0.93368208;
 -0.99948055, 0.032228146, 0.35810307;
 0, 0, 0]

U * Ut
[1.8717623, 0.33435443, 0;
 0.33435443, 1.1282378, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
```

OpenCV version is 2.4.10

Comment: Just in case anyone is not familiar with SVD = Singular Value Decomposition, it factorizes an input matrix (`H`) as the product of three special matrices (here `S` * `U` * `Vt`). Generally these are many ways to do this, but SVD restricts S and Vt to unitary matrices and U to diagonal matrices.

Comment: (Previous comment has S and U swapped; OpenCV takes its arguments in a non-standard order). It's fairly obviously wrong, U cannot have zero rows or zero columns.

Comment: I don't think it's coincidence that `0.032228146^2 + 0.99948055 ^2 = 1.0`  and `0.93368208^2 + 0.35810307^2 = 1.0`.

Comment: This seems a [known bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3801), but it should be solved. However I still have this behavior with OpenCV 3.0.0. `S` and `Vt` values are identical to MATLAB, while `U` is orthogonal in MATLAB but not in OpenCV. However, `U * S * Vt` produces the same correct result on both, i.e. the initial matrix (for OpenCV you need to put the S vector on the diagonal of a zero initialized matrix).